# How to calculate yearly average per product?

Tags: powerbi, average, dax

I am new to Power BI and the language DAX. Therefore, I find it hard to do simple yearly average across different products.

I have tried a different combination of the functions AVERAGEX and CALCULATE without any luck so far.

My table:

```
Date       | Product | Value
2014-05-06   Cheese    10
2014-08-11   Cheese    12
2015-04-11   Cheese    9
2014-01-22    Milk     4
2014-12-24    Milk     8
```

The output I try to create:

```
Date       | Product | Value | Yearly_AVG
2014-05-06   Cheese    10         11
2014-08-11   Cheese    12         11
2015-04-11   Cheese    9          9
2014-01-22    Milk     4          6
2014-12-24    Milk     8          6
```

Lastly, I do not have a calendar table in the dataset.

Comment: Do you have a calendar table or just this one? Also, are you trying to write a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: No calendar table and I am not sure whether a calculated column or a measure would be best in my situation, but I can imagine that the DAX code would be similar in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a measure, you can write something like this:

```
YearAvg =
VAR CurrProduct = VALUES ( Sales[Product] )
VAR CurrYear = YEAR ( MAX ( Sales[Date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE ( Sales[Value] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Sales ),
        Sales[Product] IN CurrProduct,
        YEAR ( Sales[Date] ) = CurrYear
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! How much would I need to change the code to make it a monthly average?

Comment: Either replace `YEAR` by `MONTH` or else add another variable `CurrMonth` and condition `MONTH(Sales[Date]) = CurrMonth` depending on if you want to average over month or over year-month.